# OpenMicroBlogging-library for Java?

Tags: java, cofundos

Can anyone recommend to me a library to communicate via [OpenMicroBlogging](http://openmicroblogging.org/)?  It should be in Java and Open Source.

**Update:** As there seem to be no OMB-library for Java, I have created a request on [cofundos](http://cofundos.org/project.php?id=169). So if you are able to create such a library, go catch the money.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Laconica http://laconi.ca/trac/ I have heard that the setup requires some effort, though I haven't tried it myself

Comment: I know about Laconica. But I want a library to include OMB-functionality in an app (or create an OMB-enabled app) and as I'm a java-programmer I look for a java-library.

Comment: Laconica is PHP, so this doesn't really help when he is looking for an java lib

Answer (score 0):

Jaiku for example is able to talk via REST. Maybe this is an alternative, as you can use simple REST libs to communicate with it.

http://www.jaiku.com/api/docs

Comment: I don't want to talk with a specific microblogging-service, I want a library that enables OMB-compatibility to talk with all microblogging-services (at least the ones supporting OMB).